# Sharepoint custom column width

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have some long words without white space in a row of Sharepoint item list. Because of that column width is really big and i need to set it to fixed value. Also I need to wrap those long words.

Found this [tutorial](http://aanuwizard.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-width-of-list-column/). It almost works, but the change is only seen in the designer and not in the browser. How else is it possible to change it?

Comment: have you cleared the cache of your browser?

Comment: Just tried it and nothing changed. I tried changing other css atributes like bacground-color and effect is seen instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to your style declarations.

Like that:

```
div { width: 300px !important; }
```